# How can an Integer be added to a String ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>() ;
list.add(1) ;
Integer hello = (Integer) list.get(0) ;
System.out.println(hello);
```

The above code has a reference of type **List** referring to an instance of **ArrayList** of type **String**. When the line `list.add(1)` is executed, isn't the 1 added to the ArrayList (of type String) ? If yes, then why is this allowed?

Comment: what does your println gives you?

Comment: Tested; It prints 1 ^

Comment: Which IDE are you using to write this code? And what compiler to compile it? It seems strange to me that your code even compiles.

Comment: @nikkatsa you get some warnings about type safety, but it does compile and run. See the answers to understand why.

Comment: @EtienneMiret Eclipse does not compile that for me. Maybe if i try to compile from command line it will be successful.

Comment: @nikkatsa Eclipse compiles it for me (with warnings). You may want to check your settings under Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings>Generic types.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have used type erasure, which means you have ignored previously set generic checks.  You can get away with this as this as generics are a compile time feature which isn't checked at runtime.

What you have the same as

```
List list = new ArrayList() ;
list.add(1) ;
Integer hello = (Integer) list.get(0) ;
System.out.println(hello);
```

or

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
list.add(1) ;
Integer hello = list.get(0); // generics add an implicit cast here
System.out.println(hello);
```

If you look at the byte code generated by the compiler, there is no way to tell the difference.

Interestingly, you can do this

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
List<Integer> ints = (List) strings;
ints.add(1);

System.out.println(strings); // ok
String s= strings.get(0); // throws a ClassCastException
```

Comment: Why does the compiler not prevent me from doing a 
List list = new ArrayList<String>() ;  ? Ideally it should have only allowed either of the above two.

Comment: Eclispe does issue a warning when you do `List list = new ArrayList<String>();`. I always though the compiler would do it too.

Comment: A lovely thing called backward compatibility.  You need to be able to assign generic collections to methods which where not written for generics.  Hopefully one day this feature will be dropped, but I doubt it.,

Comment: The Oracle/Sun Java compiler gives you a warning on the `list.add(1);` method.

Comment: Yes, I got a warning too. I was wondering why the compiler does not mark it as an error. Can you give an example of "You need to be able to assign generic collections to methods which where not written for generics"

Comment: You have a library like Apache commons collections which takes a list.  The version of the library was built to be compatible with Java 1.4.  This means you need to assign/pass a `List` as Java 1.4 doesn't support generics.

Comment: That is fine, but then I would pass an `ArrayList()` instead of and `ArrayList<String>()` . Why am I allowed to pass an `ArrayList<String>()` ? What benefit does it bring?

Comment: Say you have code which uses generics and you don't want to make all your code unsafe just to call a non-generic method in an old library.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that your `list` variable has a raw type and you can add objects of any type to this list. To solve the problem just declare it as a `List` of `String`'s:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() ;
```

Answer (score 3):

It compiles because the declaration `List list` uses the raw type `List`, not the bound type `List<String>`. The second line compiles because your `list` variable can accept anything. The third line compiles because `list.get(0)` returns `Object`. The fourth line has no reason to fail.

By accident, nothing in the compiled code caused the Integer 1 to be cast to a `String`.  But you must not depend on that. Had the first line been the proper

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

your mistake would have been caught at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a list like this:
`List list = new ArrayList<String>() ;`

You are using what's called a Raw Type.  It's a type that has a generic type parameter, like List, but you failed to supply one.  If you check the compiler warnings you will see it is telling you about this.  Mixing parameterized types with raw types is generally considered a programming error.  This is ok:

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() ;`

and this is ok (but obsolete):

`List list = new ArrayList();`

But the way you wrote it should be avoided.

The problem is generics are checked only at compiler time, and you told the compiler `List`, not `List<String>`, so it will let you put anything you want in there!  The fact that the right side has the parameter doesn't really mean anything, it's the type of the actual reference that matters to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>() ; // WARNING!!!
```

An unsafe List refers to a safe ArrayList

```
list.add(1) ;  // WARNING!!!
```

An Integer (int 1 converted to Integer is Autoboxing) not a String added to the List

```
Integer hello = (Integer) list.get(0) ;
```

Casting is required because unsafe List can contain anything.

```
System.out.println(hello);
```

Integer.toString() called

> When the line list.add(1) is executed, isn't the 1 added to the ArrayList (of type String) ?

Yes. Integer was added to an ArrayList that is supposed to contain String.

> If yes, then why is this allowed?

Backward Compatibility. Java has to support pre-generic codes.

List list; means it is unsafe so you can do anything with it and the referred ArrayList() has to tolerate that.

**Moral:** Don't ignore the compiler warnings otherwise Integer might enter into an ArrayList that is supposed to contain Strings.

Answer (score -1):

Yes... the 1 is addeded to Array, because Java, like other languages, implements implicit (automatic) conversion (casting) of primitives data types.

More information here [Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)

Comment: `String` is not a primitive and doesn't have automatic conversions.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
List.add(Integer.toString(1));
```

You also can try this

```
List list = new ArrayList<Object>() ;
```

If there is no need that the arraylist must be a Arraylist of String

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Answer (score -4):

No, because Java sees the `1` as an Integer. You will need to convert your number as a String first with `Integer.toString(n)`